# Suppose that $U$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Given its p.d.f. and c.d.f, find $P(U<a|U<b)$ for $0<a<b<1$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

Suppose that $U$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Find $P(U<a|U<b)$ for $0<a<b<1$.

---

We know that the p.d.f. of $U[a;b]$ is

$f_X(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{b-a} & :\text{for }a \leq x \leq b \\ 0 & :\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$

In our case, $U[0;1]$

$f_X(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & :\text{for } 0\leq x \leq 1 \\0 & :\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Thus, our c.d.f. is

$F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} f_X(u) du=\begin{cases}1 & : x>1 \\ \int_0^x 1 dx & : 0\leq x\leq 1 \\ 0 & :\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Regarding the main focus of our question, we know that

$P(U<a|U<b)=\frac{P(U<a, U<b)}{P(U<b)}$

However,

$P(U<a, U<b)=P(U<a)$

Thus,

$P(U<a|U<b)=\frac{P(U<a)}{P(U<b)}=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{a} f_X(u) du}{\int_{-\infty}^{b} f_X(u) du}=\frac{\int_{0}^{a} 1 du}{\int_{0}^{b} 1 du}=\frac{a}{b}$

Not totally comfortable with these concepts, so I am not sure if this answer intuitively is right or wrong. Could anyone let me know whether I am right or wrong. If I am wrong, could someone explain why, and how to find the right answer?

Comment: You're completely correct.

Comment: The intuition is that given $U\lt b$ we are dealing with the uniform on $(0,b)$, so the conditional probability is $a/b$.

Comment: MathJax tip: Don't use `\Big\{_{ }^{ }` for piecewise functions. Use `\begin{cases}\frac{1}{b-a} & : a\leq x \leq b \\ 0 & :\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}` to generate: $$\begin{cases}\frac{1}{b-a} & : a\leq x \leq b \\ 0 & :\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$